# Laravel get MySQL to query Builder statement in Eloquent model

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

Given the following table:

`+----+----------+------------+
| id | parent_id| Name       | 
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |     NULL |    Parent 1|
|  2 |        1 |     Child 1|
|  3 |        1 |     Child 2|
|  4 |        1 |     Child 3|
|  5 |     NULL |    Parent 2|
|  6 |        1 |     Child 4|
|  7 |        1 |     Child 5| 
|  8 |        1 |     Child 6|
+----+----------+------------+`

I want to select the same data, even if the provided ID is a parent or not.
So the provided ID = 1 (parent) or if the ID = 3 (child) I want to select this exact same data:

`+----+----------+------------+
| id | parent_id| Name       | 
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |     NULL |    Parent 1|
|  2 |        1 |     Child 1|
|  3 |        1 |     Child 2|
|  4 |        1 |     Child 3|
+----+----------+------------+`

I have a working MySQL query for it:

```
SELECT * FROM packages

WHERE id = 3 

OR parent_id = 3 

OR parent_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM packages WHERE id = 3)

OR id = (SELECT parent_id FROM packages WHERE id = 3)
```

So if you replace `3` with `1` you get the same results as expected.

I have already the following function in my Package Model:

```
<?php

public function related()
{
    $childParent = Package::select( 'parent_id' )->where( 'id', $this->id )->first();

    $query = $this->where( 'id', $this->id )
                  ->orWhere( 'parent_id', $this->id );

    if ( null !== $childParent->parent_id ) {
        $query
            ->orWhere( 'parent_id', $childParent->parent_id )
            ->orWhere( 'id', $childParent->parent_id );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

But this feels... well... ugly. I am coming from Symfony where this kind of queries can get easily build (and with little codelines) with the ORM query builder.

Are I am missing a feature in Laravel Eloquent to make this nice and short?

**Edit:** I got already these functions which fall both short at not selecting the other children **and** eventual parent:

```
<?php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( Package::class, 'parent_id' )->withTrashed();
}

public function childs()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Package::class, 'parent_id' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect use-case for a relationship:

```
public function parent() {
    $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children() {
    $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

---

```
$parent = Model::with('children')->find(1); // with eager loading 
$parent->children;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would probably update the answer to load the parent as well as children.

Comment: Sorry that I did not show you the rest of the code which has a `parent()` and `childs()` function which does exactly that. But I want always the parent included _and_ the siblings of a child too. Thats why I got this ugly solution as posted on top. ;-)